# New GPU AMD kernel driver issues with kfd rules

Tags: drivers, kernel, git

I installed a new used gpu (Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]).  It froze on boot and I used grub recovery mode to try and fiddle with the drivers from amd. I found this command which supposedly installs all the possible amd gpu drivers:

> sudo apt-get install git && git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git && sudo cp -v -u linux-firmware/amdgpu/* /lib/firmware/amdgpu && sudo update-initramfs -uk all

After this I tried rebooting which got me to the point where I had access to TTY. This is the sudo journalctl -p 3 -xb output

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-11-04 19:03:22 EST, end at Wed 2021-02-10 20:59:38 EST. --
Feb 10 20:40:39 desktop kernel: kfd kfd: amdgpu: TAHITI  not supported in kfd
Feb 10 20:40:39 desktop systemd-udevd[419]: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-amdgpu.rules:1 Invalid operator for GROUP.
Feb 10 20:40:43 desktop sddm[1063]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Feb 10 20:40:43 desktop sddm[1063]: Display server failed to start. Exiting
Feb 10 20:40:44 desktop sddm[1835]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Feb 10 20:40:44 desktop sddm[1835]: Display server failed to start. Exiting
Feb 10 20:40:46 desktop sddm[1926]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Feb 10 20:40:46 desktop sddm[1926]: Display server failed to start. Exiting
Feb 10 20:40:47 desktop sddm[2067]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Feb 10 20:40:47 desktop sddm[2067]: Display server failed to start. Exiting
Feb 10 20:40:49 desktop sddm[2756]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Feb 10 20:40:49 desktop sddm[2756]: Display server failed to start. Exiting
Feb 10 20:40:50 desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
-- Subject: A start job for unit gpu-manager.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit gpu-manager.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 1253 and the job result is failed.
Feb 10 20:40:50 desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Simple Desktop Display Manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit sddm.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit sddm.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 1178 and the job result is failed.
Feb 10 20:40:59 desktop systemd[3784]: mpd.socket: Failed to create listening socket ([::]:6600): Address already in use
```

The only thing that works currently is nomodeset in /etc/default/grub.

The output to

> cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-amdgpu.rules

Is:

> KERNEL=="kfd", GROUP=="video", MODE="0660"

After trying to remove the udev rule that causes the error i get this:

```
Feb 11 14:51:25 desktop kernel: kfd kfd: amdgpu: TAHITI  not supported in kfd
Feb 11 14:51:25 desktop kernel: kfd kfd: amdgpu: error getting iommu info. is the iommu enabled?
Feb 11 14:51:25 desktop kernel: kfd kfd: amdgpu: Error initializing iommuv2
Feb 11 14:51:25 desktop kernel: kfd kfd: amdgpu: device 1002:15dd NOT added due to errors
Feb 11 14:51:29 desktop sddm[1100]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Feb 11 14:51:29 desktop sddm[1100]: Display server failed to start. Exiting
Feb 11 14:51:30 desktop sddm[1817]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Feb 11 14:51:30 desktop sddm[1817]: Display server failed to start. Exiting
Feb 11 14:51:32 desktop sddm[1953]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Feb 11 14:51:32 desktop sddm[1953]: Display server failed to start. Exiting
Feb 11 14:51:33 desktop sddm[2083]: Failed to read display number from pipe
 Feb 11 14:51:33 desktop sddm[2083]: Display server failed to start. Exiting
Feb 11 14:51:35 desktop sddm[2633]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Feb 11 14:51:35 desktop sddm[2633]: Display server failed to start. Exiting
Feb 11 14:51:36 desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
-- Subject: A start job for unit gpu-manager.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit gpu-manager.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1238 and the job result is failed.
 Feb 11 14:51:36 desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Simple Desktop Display Manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit sddm.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit sddm.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1163 and the job result is failed.
Feb 11 14:52:20 desktop systemd[4019]: mpd.socket: Failed to create listening socket ([::]:6600): Address already in use
Feb 11 14:52:20 desktop systemd[4019]: Failed to listen on mpd.socket.
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 22 and the job result is failed.
```

Feb 11 14:52:20 desktop systemd[4019]: Failed to start Music Player Daemon.
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 26 and the job result is failed.

Here are my system specs.

[System Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIGIq.png)

OS:Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64

Kernel: 5.4.0-65-generic

DE: Plasma

Some additional info that might be pertinent:

-Ksplashqml crashes every time I log in to the desktop environment and if I click restart the application the desktop environment crashes and I'm back to TTY.

-Every time I close out of Konsole it says that Konsole has closed unexpectedly. A few other programs do this but not all of them. Firefox doesn't do this for some reason.

-Both of my monitors display the same output. Xrandr gives me this

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1920x1080     77.00*
```

Comment: Added. Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64 with the kernel : 5.4.0-65-generic. I'm not sure what GA or HWE means. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-amdgpu.rules` Please add this to your question.

Comment: Added. The output is:
 
    KERNEL=="kfd", GROUP=="video", MODE="0660

Comment: Try this `sudo mv  /etc/udev/rules.d/70-amdgpu.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/70-amdgpu.rules.bak` this way your system ignore this udev rule.

Comment: Ok I tried it and it failed.  I added the journalctl error log above.  Would it be possible to add the rule back and just change the operator to allow TAHITI? I know nothing about udev rules. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please try bootoption `iommu=pt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this post regarding that.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626002/etc-udev-rules-d-70-amdgpu-rules1-invalid-operator-for-group-found-in-error-l

Seems like there is one too many `==` in `GROUP=="video"`, I've changed mine to `GROUP="video"` and the "Invalid Opearator for GROUP" error desapears.

Comment: I reimaged my computer but this seems right. == is true/false and = is assignment.